# Background img not displaying when file changed from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, css

The design for the website I am working on was created using HTML. When I changed the file from .html to .php the background image stopped loading.

Is there a reason .php files won't load a background image?

If so, is there a work around to get it to load?

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="full-page login-page" data-color="blue" data-image="./assets/img/hola.jpg">
```

I can navigate to the file path in the browser, and I've adjusted the file permissions through my host, but still no luck.

Appreciate any help!

[edit]
Not sure if this matters, but when I open chrome's dev tools and switch to the network tab, the image is NOT displaying on the img load list.

Comment: have u see the server log?, other idea is the path "./", using absolute "/" will work?

Comment: If you mean error log, there is not one being produced. Changing the path to absolute does not work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, something with the `data-image` selector was not working correctly, adding a `background-image` style to the `div` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Were you using the same server for the HTML file as you are for the PHP one? If you were not using a server for the HTML file, my guess is that the server interpreting the PHP file has a different notion of the current working directory than the HTML file had.

If you put something like this into the file to print the current working directory using PHP, does it show the directory where the file actually resides?

```
<?= getcwd() ?>
```

Comment: I was developing locally when I first noticed the image wasn't displaying and I used the same exact path to the image in both files.

Comment: You've lost me there. Where should I be placing that script and what info are you hoping to receive back?

Comment: I meant to place it in the PHP file where your code above was taken from, and checking if it returns a directory which contains the file `assets/img/hola.jpg`. Then again, the attribute above won't load the file, but it can be set from the attribute by JavaScript or (I think) CSS. So that could affect where the file is looked for as well. Anyway, it seems you solved the problem :).